# How to redirect to a page in python

Tags: python, redirect

```js
def do_GET(self):
    if self.path == "/":
        self.path = "/index.html"

    elif self.path == "/train":
        self.path = "/train.html"
        self.threadHandle = threading.Thread(target = redirection) #Initiate a method from the thread
        self.threadHandle.daemon = True
        self.threadHandle.start()

def redirection():
    print "In redirection method"
    time.sleep(2)
    self.send_response(301)
    self.send_header('Location','/index')
    self.end_headers()
```

I want to start a seperate thread once the train page is hit and rendered. Once the thread starts and completes its job i need to redirect it to the index page. Can you please explain what i need to do and what i am doing wrong in this approach. This is the pure python server code. I am NOT using any frameworks.

Comment: You should add some context. Where does those functions sit? What framework/libs are you using? How are you communicating with the client?

Comment: @spectras i have added some context. I hope it helps

Comment: The redirection method over here is a global method in the server.

Comment: I think you should get more familiar with HTTP flow. To redirect you should just return 301 response like you did but 'sleep' should most probably belong to your front end code no matter what you expected it to be there for.

Comment: The problem is I need the training page to get rendered not just redirect. If i just use redirection then it does not render the training page.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Flask and here is what I do: `return redirect(url_for('method_name'))`.  I would definitely recommend using it as well since it makes web development much cleaner.

It has nice wrappers that can help you do authentication, define what actions work for what routes( say for your index page you only want GET).

Comment: I know but the project i am working is already in completion phase so i cant change it any frameworks for now. Thanks anyway for a suggestion

Comment: what web server are you using? Apache?

Comment: Its a simple python server.